# AttributeError: 'numpy.datetime64' object has no attribute 'toordinal' in python 3 CLoudera

Tags: python, cloudera

I am trying to do some time series analysis, but I get an error when I try to plot the result of seasonal_decompose().

Time series looks like below (it was generated from a bigger dataframe): 
**df1** 
|----------------|outflow_sum|
|val_date   ----**|**----------------|
|2020-04-01 **|** 249
|2019-10-01 **|** 19474
|2019-12-01 **|** 889
|2019-12-01 **|** 15149
|2020-04-01 **|** 5334
|..................    **|** ...
|2019-12-01 **|** 7146
|2020-09-01 **|** 17898
|2020-01-01 **|** 110
|2020-06-01 **|** 750
|2020-09-01 **|** 25191

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from datetime import datetime
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
register_matplotlib_converters()

df1 = df[['val_date','outflow_sum']]
df1['val_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['val_date'], format='%Y-%m')
df1.set_index(df1['val_date'],inplace=True)
df1.drop('val_date',axis=1, inplace=True)
```

And when I try to do:

```
result = seasonal_decompose(df1,model='additive', freq = 1)
result.plot()
```

I get the error for the plot saying:
AttributeError: 'numpy.datetime64' object has no attribute 'toordinal'

I am using Python 3 in the Cloudera interface.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted! Instead of setting the 'val_date' as an index, just left it as a datetime column and the decomposition worked.